# Proving $e^{sT}$ tends to $0$, as $T$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let us define a curve $\gamma$ (orientated counterclockwise) as the boundary
of the region $\{s \in \mathbb C : |s| ≤ R, \sigma > -\delta\}$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

$\gamma_- = \gamma \cap  \{σ < 0\}$.

I read in a thesis that, as $T$ tends to $\infty$, $e^{sT}$ tends to $0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\gamma_-$, but the proof was not given,

I have been told that $\sigma < 0 $and $\sigma$ takes a maximum on closed and bounded sets. but I could not follow how that proves the statement.
From a comment, I got, 
$M:=\max_{\sigma'\in K } \sigma' < 0$,
$K\subset\gamma_-$ compact,

$|e^{sT}| = e^{\sigma T} \leq e^{ M T} < \varepsilon \iff T > (\log\varepsilon) / M > 0.$

but the inference from last line + inequality is not clear to me.

Could anyone please provide the **complete and detail proof**?

Thanks.

Comment: $M:=\max_{\sigma'\in K } \sigma' < 0$, $K\subset\gamma_-$ compact,
$$|e^{sT}| = e^{\sigma T} \leq e^{ M T} < \varepsilon \iff
T > (\log\varepsilon) / M > 0.$$

Comment: Andrew, please first write the definition of uniform convergence in terms of an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, $s$ and $T$. Second, what is unclear about the inequality to you? Do you understand that, for real numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y > 0$, $e^x < y$ is equivalent to $x < \log(y)$? The symbol "$\iff$" means "if and only if", an equivalence.

Comment: Actually, maybe it is worthwhile asking whether it is clear to you that $$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} e^{\sigma T} = 0$$
for each $\sigma \in \gamma_-$ (not uniformly).

Comment: @snar your first point is not clear, how in terms of uniform of convergence the proof works, also the role of compact set is not clear.

Comment: Could you please address whether you understand that $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty} e^{\sigma T} = 0$ for all $\sigma \in \gamma_-$, but not necessarily uniformly in $\sigma$? It will help me answer the question.

Comment: @snar yes that part is ok, also please include the the idea of compact set.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223408/visual-representation-of-difference-between-closed-bounded-and-compact-sets

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/closedness-of-compact-sets-in-a-metric-space

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-way-to-understand-compactness?_escaped_fragment_=n%3D12&redirected_qid=5562325

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109731/is-open-cover-an-open-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked to prove that
$$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} e^{s T} = 0$$
uniformly on compact subsets of $\sigma_-$. The definition of this is that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and any compact set $K \subset \gamma_-$, there is $\mathcal{T} < \infty$ such that for all $T \geq \mathcal{T}$, 
$$e^{s T} < \varepsilon$$
for all $s \in K$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $K$ be given, and assume without loss of generality that $\varepsilon < 1$. Since the function $f(\sigma) = \sigma$ is continuous, it achieves its maximum on the compact set $K\subset\{\sigma < 0\}$. Let $M = \max_{\sigma \in K} \sigma$, and note that $M < 0$. For this given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\mathcal{T} = \log\varepsilon / M$ and observe that since $M < 0$, $\mathcal{T} > 0$. Then, for any $s \in K$ and $T \geq \mathcal{T}$, we have $s \leq M < 0$ and
$$e^{s T} \leq e^{M T} \leq e^{M \mathcal{T}} = \varepsilon,$$
as required.